# Property application was circularly defined in ANT Build.xml

Tags: ant, build.xml

I am running a build.xml which is referring to the property file named ant.properties and I have declared the same in my build.xml but when i run the build.xml on my Linux machine it gives below error
build.xml:15: Property application was circularly defined.

It is working fine with an existing windows VDI but now we are migrating to new Linux server and hence tried the same existing build and properties file

property file="ant.properties" is what I am using in my build.xml

I am not sure why it is saying circularly defined as I am sure nothing is running gin loop and my properties file does not have reference back to my build.xml to create a loop.

Comment: This is due to something in your properties file being defined like `property.name=${property.name}`. Please post the contents of your properties file so the issue can be debugged.

Comment: Thank you Austin, you were bang on. Unknowingly I had defined a property as env=${env}. The error is gone after removing that. Appreciate your quick response

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to us due to us referencing a property which had not been added to our properties file. As a result ant was trying to pull the property from the same one that was being declared.

**Bad declaration:**

```
<entry key="my.prop.name" value="${my.prop.name}"/>
```

To fix it we just had to add a check to see if the property was set or not as it was an optional one.

```
<if>
    <isset property="my.prop.name" />
    <then>
        <propertyfile file="path/to/config.properties">
            <entry key="my.prop.name" value="${my.prop.name}"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </then>
</if>
```

This fixed our circular dependency issue and allowed the property to be optional in the project.